# GDPR banner on network sites without account

Tags: feature-request, gdpr

Sometimes when browsing the hot network questions I see the GDPR banner on every network site where I haven't made an account because I don't want to participate actively. Dismissing it just makes it come back after a while. Could the dismissal be remembered cross-network?

Comment: This sounds okay, but how would you implement it? If you don't want to have an account (i.e. provide a way for SE to identify you)--which is fine--the system can't really tell if you've dismissed the banner before and are visiting again, or if you're someone new with the same IP and browser.

Comment: Can't they write a sitewide cookie saying that I dismissed the banner already? (I'm not a webdev, so that might be completely impossible)

Comment: Assuming that it is possible, that doesn't solve the problem; a cookie doesn't know whether you're you or someone else using your computer. I guess it comes down to whether GDPR requires notification of the actual human person or just a machine/an IP address. (I don't know what GDPR actually says, and I am not a lawyer).